# Kerberos - Maximum renewable lifetime

Tags: kerberos

I am trying to set the maximum renewable lifetime of the issued Kerberos tickets to 365 days, however, the following changes that I have made seem to be ignored:

Inside **/etc/krb5.conf**:

```
[libdefaults]
...
    renew_lifetime = 365d
...

[appdefaults]
    pam = {
    ...
       renew_lifetime = 365d 
    ...
    }
```

Within a **kadmin** session:

```
kadmin:  modprinc -maxrenewlife 365day krbtgt/REALM
kadmin:  modprinc -maxrenewlife 365day stefan
```

I then proceeded to issue a new ticket via **kinit**:

```
$ kinit -r 365d
```

However, the resulting ticket has a renew lifetime of 7 days only:

```
$ klist
Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_1000
Default principal: stefan@REALM

Valid starting       Expires              Service principal
2017-03-09 21:15:31  2017-03-10 09:15:31  krbtgt/REALM@REALM
    renew until 2017-03-16 21:15:31
```

Did I miss something? I am using MIT Kerberos Version 1.13.7.

**EDIT:** I solved the problem by adding the **max_renewable_life** parameter to the realms section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding the **max_renewable_life** parameter to the realms section.

```
[realms]
    REALM = {
        ...
        max_renewable_life = 365d
    }
```